# EclipseLink inheritance queries: Avoid joining

Tags: java, inheritance, eclipselink

Right now, In a short example, if i have two entities `Person` and `Applicant` and i want to write a query that gets all applicants in my database, i end up getting referenced queries with the following set up. I am using Single_Table_Inheritance strategy (fyi)

```
public class Person {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "schoolID")
    private School school;
}
```

The Teacher object with a reference to another entity.

```
public class Applicant extends Person {

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = ApplicantSchool.class, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST, javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy = "applicant")
    private Set<ApplicantSchool> schools = new HashSet<ApplicantSchool>();
}
```

Query attempt that jumps and attempts to query for the school relationship in Person

```
 public List<Applicant> getAllApplicants(){

        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Applicant> applicants = entityManager.createQuery("Select a from Applicant a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.schools WHERE a.active = :active ")
        .setParameter("active", true).setHint("eclipselink.refresh", "true")
        .getResultList();
        //List<Applicant> applicants =  Applicant.findAllApplicants();
        System.out.println("The long query getting applicants");
        entityManager.close();
        return applicants;  
    }
```

If i try to change my query to use nested joining, i get an error saying relationship not recognized. I tried to query like so:

```
entityManager.createQuery("Select a from Applicant a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.schools WHERE LEFT JOIN FETCH a.person.school a.active = :active ")
```

**UPDATED**

After removing the keyword "left join fetch" my new query:

```
List<Applicant> applicants = entityManager.createQuery("Select a from Applicant a WHERE a.active = :active ")
        .setParameter("active", true)
        .getResultList();
```

The only query i agree with that it first creates is this one

```
SELECT personID, TYPE, DATEADDED, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, ACTIVE, BIRTHDAY, EMAILADDRESS, ETHNICITY, GENDER, HISPANIC, IMAGEPATH, MARITAL, NATIVELANGUAGE, PRIMARYTELEPHONE, RELIGIOUSAFFILIATION, SECONDARYTELEPHONE, version, addressID, schoolID, MAJOR FROM PERSON WHERE ((ACTIVE = ?) AND (TYPE = ?))
    bind => [true, AP]
```

Returns this stack trace and the following sql's selects are created:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.297--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(726700617)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT schoolID, ACTIVE, ADMISSIONSEMAILADDRESS, ADMISSIONSPHONE, CODE, description, HELPGENERALEMAILADDRESS, NAME, PRIMARYPHONE, version, addressID FROM SCHOOL WHERE (schoolID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.305--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(1615948530)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT id, ACTIVE, CODE, DESCRIPTION, NAME, version, SCHOOLDEPARTMENT_schoolID FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE (SCHOOLDEPARTMENT_schoolID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.308--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(893810654)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT programID, ACTIVE, CODE, description, NAME, PROGRAMTYPE, REQUIREDCREDITS, version, SCHOOL_schoolID FROM PROGRAM WHERE (SCHOOL_schoolID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.31--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(399107363)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT personID, TYPE, DATEADDED, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, ACTIVE, BIRTHDAY, EMAILADDRESS, ETHNICITY, GENDER, HISPANIC, IMAGEPATH, MARITAL, NATIVELANGUAGE, PRIMARYTELEPHONE, RELIGIOUSAFFILIATION, SECONDARYTELEPHONE, version, addressID, schoolID, MAJOR, studentId FROM PERSON WHERE (schoolID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.314--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(464642021)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT registrationId, SEMESTERTYPE, version, YEAR, semesterCourseId, personID FROM REGISTRATION WHERE (personID = ?)
    bind => [501]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.322--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(395757277)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT registrationId, SEMESTERTYPE, version, YEAR, semesterCourseId, personID FROM REGISTRATION WHERE (personID = ?)
    bind => [552]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.327--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(328677993)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT registrationId, SEMESTERTYPE, version, YEAR, semesterCourseId, personID FROM REGISTRATION WHERE (personID = ?)
    bind => [602]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.358--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(873312397)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT addressID, CITY, COUNTRY, STATE_US, STREETADDRESS, STREETADDRESS2, version, ZIPCODE FROM ADDRESS WHERE (addressID = ?)
    bind => [2]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.365--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(509650638)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT applicantSchoolID, CREDITSCOMPLETED, FROMMONTH, FROMYEAR, GPA, NAME, SCHOOLTYPE, TOMONTH, TOYEAR, version, APPLICANT_personID FROM APPLICANTSCHOOL WHERE (APPLICANT_personID = ?)
    bind => [151]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-13 17:25:52.385--ServerSession(1529073996)--Connection(17334753)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-18,5,main])--SELECT applicantSchoolID, CREDITSCOMPLETED, FROMMONTH, FROMYEAR, GPA, NAME, SCHOOLTYPE, TOMONTH, TOYEAR, version, APPLICANT_personID FROM APPLICANTSCHOOL WHERE (APPLICANT_personID = ?)
    bind => [51]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's an applicant? How is it related to Person and Teacher? What would you like the query to return?

Comment: I am sorry i changed the example to applicant, it would be the same idea as Applicant inherits Person as well. Updated the question to applicant. I want to return all Applicants but dont want need the school field which as i have added has many other relationships that get all loaded eagerly by default and when i try to use nested joins to fetch, i dont have access to my parents fields?

Comment: The above query retrieves applicants, each with their set of schools. You would like the applicants with their set of schools, but without all the eagerly-fetched association in the school entity, is that right?

Comment: Actually at that stage no, i dont even want the applicant schools but if i dont specify to join with the applicant schools it goes and fetches each applicants school with multiple select statements. By specifying a left join fetch i can get them in one query. I would like to just get a list of applicants without any relationships both immediate ones and ones coming from inherited classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest join in JPA, but you shouldn't need to when querying on Applicant.
JPQL "Select a from Applicant a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.schools LEFT JOIN FETCH a.school where a.active = :active " should work, since Appliant IS a Person and so has the school relationship.  Nesting is only if Applicant has a relation to person and you needed to fetch join both person and school.

If that is the case, EclipseLink allows batch reading or joins through query hints described here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/QueryOptimization

You can also specify batching/fetch joins at the mapping level using EclipseLink annotations described here:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_batchfetch.htm#CHDCCIDA
and 
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_joinfetch.htm#CEGFFHHA

Batch reading will result in 2 queries, while fetch joins in 1.

For the query described above, you could also use:

```
em.createQuery("Select a from Applicant a WHERE a.active = :active ")
         .setParameter("active", true)
         .setQueryHint("eclipselink.left-join-fetch", "a.schools");
         .setQueryHint("eclipselink.left-join-fetch", "a.school");
         .getResultList();
```

Comment: Your querying method helped as well as the batch fetching documentation.